# What is the default behavior for items added to System.Web.Caching.Cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What are the default expiration parameters associated with items added to the ASP.NET cache?

Do items added expire after an absolute period of time, and if so, what is the default expiration time? Or do they use a sliding-window?

I can't seem to find any references to default behavior of items added and I need to know because I am supporting a code-base where all calls to the Cache are done via Cache[key] = value rather than specifying explicit dependencies / expiration policies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.item.aspx) this is equivalent to [Cache.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bawy15w.aspx) which means

> The object added to the cache using this overload of the Insert method
>   is inserted with no file or cache dependencies, a priority of Default,
>   a sliding expiration value of NoSlidingExpiration, and an absolute
>   expiration value of NoAbsoluteExpiration.

Effectively this means that ASP.NET will manage it based on memory pressure.

Answer (score 2):

By default, items committed to cache will remain there until memory is low and ASP.NET decides it has something more important to store.

Answer (score 0):

From [ASP.NET Caching: Techniques and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx)

> The simplest way to store data in the Cache is simply to assign it,
>   using a key, just like a HashTable or Dictionary object:

```
Cache["key"] = "value";
```

> **This will store the item in the cache without any dependencies, so it will not expire unless the cache engine removes it in order to make
>   room for additional cached data.**